# Dereferencing a pointer to a frame that doesn't exist anymore

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have `MessagesViewer` frame that I want to control the uniqueness of,

with this piece of code:

```
MessagesViewer* m_pMsgViewer = NULL;

void Application::ShowMessagesViewer()
{
    if (m_pMsgViewer == NULL)
    {
        m_pMsgViewer = new MessagesViewer(
            wxGetApp().GetContainer()->GetAppData()->GetMessages()
        );
    }
    else
    {
        m_pMsgViewer->FillPage(wxGetApp().GetContainer()->GetAppData()->GetMessages());
        m_pMsgViewer->SetFocus();
    }
}
```

But when I call this for the first time, `m_pMsgViewer` starts to refer to valid data in the memory. When I close `MessagesViewer` frame, it destroys it automatically, but the pointer is still referencing to old address, and I can't control destroying the frame from this client code.

How can I dereference a pointer to destroyed frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@bogdan already proposed a good solution, but there is another, even more automatic one: store your frame pointer in [wxWeakRef<>](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_weak_ref_3_01_t_01_4.html) instead. I.e. keep exactly the same code as now but replace the declaration with

```
wxWeakRef<MessagesViewer> m_pMsgViewer;
```

The weak reference will be automagically reset to `NULL` when the window is destroyed.

Comment: Nice one, didn't know about `wxWeakRef`. But... wouldn't this solution be open to the problem I mentioned at the end of my answer? Looking at the code, the inner pointer is reset inside the destructor of `wxTrackable`, from which `wxWindow` inherits (via `wxEvtHandler`). So, in our case, the `wxWeakRef` is only reset when `MessagesViewer`'s destructor runs.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it could happen in principle. `IsBeingDeleted()` could be used to check for this, i.e. the full test becomes `if (m_pMsgViewer == NULL || m_pMsgViewer->IsBeingDeleted())`.

Comment: Suggestion: I wonder what would happen if we (you :) ) added a duplicate set of calls to `wxTrackerNode::OnObjectDestroy()`, similar to the ones in `~wxTrackable()`, to `wxTopLevelWindowBase::Destroy()` (maybe guarded by a flag to avoid doing them again later on in the destructor). That would provide both maximum safety and early notification; I think both call sites are needed, since a TLW can be destroyed in multiple ways. However, I'm a bit worried that this would mess other things up, since it looks like the tracking mechanism is used by `wxEvtHandler` as well. What do you think?

Comment: This would indeed be a possible enhancement, but it would probably need to be done at `wxTrackable` level to avoid the double call to `OnObjectDestroy()`. But this is not really related to this question any more so at this stage I'd rather discuss this on wx-dev mailing list if you're interested...

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to set `m_pMsgViewer` back to `nullptr` when `MessagesViewer` is closed. A safe way to do that is to add a handler for `wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW` to your frame. For example, add the following code to `MessagesViewer`'s constructor:

```
Bind(wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, [](wxCloseEvent& evt)
{
   m_pMsgViewer = nullptr;
   evt.Skip();
});
```

`evt.Skip()` lets the event propagate further to the default handler provided by wx.

This simple example assumes that `m_pMsgViewer` is a global variable. If it's actually contained within the `Application` object, you'll have to add some way to access it.

---

The obvious alternative of adding such code to `MessagesViewer`'s *destructor* is not a very good idea, as the actual destruction of the `MessagesViewer` object is delayed [according to the docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_windowdeletion.html), so it would be theoretically possible for `Application::ShowMessagesViewer()` to call `FillPage()` on a frame that has been closed and marked for destruction but not actually destroyed yet.

Handling the close event resets the pointer early on, thus avoiding the problem above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark somehow that MessagesViwer has been destroyed and cannot be referenced any more. This means some extra info in addition to m_pMsgViewer.